# Mysql variable not working through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query woking absolutely fine when entered directly:

```
SET @new_sno=0; 
SELECT(@new_sno:=@new_sno+1) AS sno_new,Products,Price,
    case sno WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 3 THEN 3 WHEN 4 THEN 4 
             WHEN 12 THEN 5 
            ELSE 6 
    END AS orderpriority 
FROM   rates ORDER BY orderpriority,sno;
```

but when I use it in php like

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SET @new_sno=0; 
    SELECT(@new_sno:=@new_sno+1) AS sno_new,Products,Price,
      case sno WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 3 THEN 3 WHEN 4 THEN 4 
            WHEN 12 THEN 5 
            ELSE 6 
      END AS orderpriority 
FROM rates ORDER BY orderpriority,sno");
```

The above statement is returning false
What can be the solution?

Comment: in case you are using multiple `queries` you need to use `mysqli_free_result($result)` between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) of mysqli.

Or move initialization.

```
SELECT(@new_sno:=@new_sno+1) AS sno_new,Products,Price,case sno WHEN 1
THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 3 THEN 3 WHEN 4 THEN 4 WHEN 12 THEN 5 ELSE 6 END AS
orderpriority 
FROM rates, (select @new_sno:=0) `tmp` -- there
ORDER BY orderpriority,sno;
```

Or simply execute it one by one.

Comment: For background, `mysqli_query()` will only accept one query (delimited by a `;`) to prevent SQL injection. They have implemented the multi_query option to circumvent this.

Comment: Hi.. I just searched the use of 'tmp' -- there, I cudn find much, as a matter of fact I dint understand the query,I want to know about it, can u enlighten me? any other resources other than mysql docs please?

Comment: @user2401175, it's derived table. Sorry, but better to start from mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html